# StrToFloat and who is wrong: Delphi or ASE/SQL Server

Tags: delphi, double, ieee-754

Recently I found strange thing: result of

```
var
  d: double;
begin
  d := StrToFloat('-1.79E308');
```

is not the same as string value '-1.79E308' converted to float field type by ASE and SQL Server through

```
INSERT INTO my_table (my_float_field) VALUES (-1.79E308)
```

For Delphi memory dump is `9A BB AD 58 F1 DC EF FF`
For ASE/SQL Server value in packet on select is `99 BB AD 58 F1 DC EF FF`.

Who is wrong, both servers or Delphi?

Comment: You didn't mention Delphi version.

Comment: Delphi 10. It is inner tests with test values as strings. As for me they converting it in different ways. I wonder which one closer to 'proper'.

Comment: This online tool http://www.binaryconvert.com/result_double.html?decimal=045049046055057069051048056 confirms that Delphi is wrong. If so it is Delphi bug.

Comment: Interestingly enough, XE5 gives the "right" result in 32 bits, and the "wrong" one in 64 bits. I kindda expected to opposite.

Comment: Yes, I found that in 64-bit under Windows. Not sure now is it the same for all platforms.

Comment: [Read this](http://rvelthuis.de/articles/articles-floats.html), [then this](http://www.davdata.nl/math/floatingpoint.html)

Comment: [`StrToFloat`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/Seattle/en/System.SysUtils.StrToFloat) returns `Extended` which is ["downgraded"](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/XE8/en/64-bit_Windows_Data_Types_Compared_to_32-bit_Windows_Data_Types) to Double on Win64. You can still use [`TExtended80Rec`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE8/en/System.TExtended80Rec) as a workaround (but no arithmetic operations).

Comment: @TOndrej, it's actually the other way around. Extended is downgraded to double in Win32. In Win64, Extended is just an alias for Double. That's why I actually expected 32 bits to exhibit the problem and not 64 bits. The source of the problem : `StrToFloat`in 32 bits use `_Pow10` to calculate the value while 64 bits use `Power10`, and the latter appears to be less precise than the former. (XE5)

Comment: @KenBourassa Perhaps I was not clear, sorry. What I meant was `Extended` is still `Extended` in Win32 but only `Double` in Win64.

Comment: In Delphi XE `D:= StrToFloat('-1.79E308');` is broken (raises exception); on the other hand good old `Val('-1.79E308', D, Code);` works and produces correct result.

Comment: Yet still we should get exactly the same value no matter Delphi 32, 64 or made with C compiler for double precision float.

Comment: @user2091150 That is correct. `StrToFloat` should yield the closest binary floating point value to the decimal value provided as the argument

Comment: If I assign a double constant directly, I get a hex value ending in `99`, in 32 and 64 bit targets. The problem is clearly in the Win64 bit version of `StrToFloat`, since only that gives me a value ending in `9a`. If you look at the sources, you'll see that the Win32 version uses Extended as intermediate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The premise that we are working from is that `StrToFloat` yields the closest representable binary floating point value to the supplied decimal value.

The two hexadecimal values the you present are adjacent. You can see that they differ by `1` in the significand. Here is some Python code that decodes the two values:

```
>>> import struct
>>> struct.unpack('!d', 'ffefdcf158adbb9a'.decode('hex'))[0]
-1.7900000000000002e+308
>>> struct.unpack('!d', 'ffefdcf158adbb99'.decode('hex'))[0]
-1.79e+308
```

Bear in mind that Python prints floating point values using the shortest possible significant for which the closest representable value is the actual value. That `ffefdcf158adbb99` decodes to a value the prints as `-1.79e+308` in the eyes of Python, is sufficient proof that `ffefdcf158adbb99` is the closest representable value. In other words, the Delphi code is giving the wrong answer.

And, just out of curiosity, in the opposite direction:

```
>>> hex(struct.unpack('<Q', struct.pack('<d', float('-1.79e308')))[0])
'0xffefdcf158adbb99L'
```

It is interesting to note that the 32 bit Delphi compiler yields `ffefdcf158adbb99` but the 64 bit Delphi compiler yields `ffefdcf158adbb9a`. This is a clear defect, and should be submitted as a bug report to Quality Portal.

Comment: Does 64 bit compiler generate code with SSE instead of x87? If yes, denormalized numbers (like this value) probably might be treated in different ways.

Comment: I reported it at https://quality.embarcadero.com/browse/RSP-13096 . Will see what Emarcadero will say.

Comment: @MBo -1.79E308 is not denormalized (aka subnormal). It is a little bigger than negative infinity.

Comment: @MBo On x64, the floating point unit is SSE. But that's not the point. Both x87 and SSE units are IEEE754 compliant and both can be coded to get this right. The defect is in the Delphi RTL code.

Comment: And note that the compiler is 32 bit in both cases, so there should not be any difference. The value ending in 9A is indeed one ulp too high, probably due to bad rounding.